# Is &vec[0] defined behavior for a std::vector vec?

Tags: c++, c++11

I see this a lot:

```
std::vector<Something> vec;
do_something_with_vec(vec);
Something *arr=&vec[0];
do_something_that_needs_carray(arr);
```

I mean, a vector will probably use an array internally so I see why this works, I'm just wondering whether or not this is defined behavior (like, is an implementor allowed to run an implementation of std::vector with which this would break).

If there are conflicts between the standards, I'm interested in what the C++11 standard says.

Comment: Not *probably* -- a `vector` **will** use contigious memory.

Comment: "*If there are conflicts between the standards, I'm interested in what the C++11 standard says.*" C++98 did not guarantee that this would work, but C++03 and C++11 do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it is allowed, if the `std::vector` is not empty. If the `vector` is empty, `vec[0]` will evoke Undefined Behavior.

`std::vector` is required to store elements contiguously.

There is also `data(`) method, but it is C++11 only.

Important:

This will not work on `std::vector<bool>` (bit-efficient specialization). But it is also not a container, and IMO it should be deprecated.

Answer (score 9):

That is fine. But if `vec` is empty, it is undefined behavior. Better use `vec.data()` which will also work if `vec` is empty.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's fine because the elements are guaranteed to be stored contiguously. The standard acknowledges this:

> The elements of a vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if `v` is a `vector<T, Allocator>` where `T` is some type other than `bool`, then it obeys the identity `&v[n] == &v[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < v.size()`.